# Wordpress visual editor not making line breaks

Tags: html, wordpress

This should be very simple, i can not believe that a company the size of Wordpress cannot provide users a very simple way to make line breaks.

I know how to use the text tab and code the page using html (im a developer). However my clients have absolutely no idea what html is so they obviously can not use it.

All the client wants to do is make a "space between lines" , in our terms a break line. They only want to use the visual editor.

Now when they start typing and hit enter, it creates & nbsp; or closes a paragraph tag.

Many articles are saying that shift + enter will make one, however this 100% does not as ive tried.

Ive tried a plugin that most articles are suggesting called "tinymce advanced". But this does not resolve the problem.

Is there any way possible for a normal user with no html knowledge to only use the visual editor and create br lines without actually using code?

Comment: I'm also facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> definitely works.

Alternatively, you can always prevent Wordpress from automatically adding `<p>` tags to the markup using the following code inside of your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but i am holding down shift + enter which is 100% not working. Should this work with or without a plugin?

Comment: What do you expect Shift+Enter to do? It doesn't place `<br />` tag inside of the markup within the visual editor. It prevents Wordpress' `wpautop` function from treating the carriage return as an automatic `<p>` tag.

Comment: so lets say a user wants to press enter 4 times, they can see a big gap now in the editor but when they save it doesnt reflect having 4 breaklines. SO how do we do this?

Comment: You need to disable Wordpress' `wpautop` as I said in the post.

Answer (score 1):

This small code fixed my issue.

```
echo nl2br(category_description( the_content);
```

Just replace the content tag with this in you file

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my site, it began when I updated the theme, which had not been updated for years. 
The "miraculous" solution was to update 
all the plugins as well.

I have realized that the

<br /  > and the   < p >

symbols are not present in the wp editor in text mode
So there must be a conversion between \n (newline) and  <br /  > and < p >  taking place, I have not investigated this further, but maybe somebody can explain how WordPress is working.

Answer (score 0):

With the WordPress upgrade to version 3.2, the text editor seems to remove the line break by itself.

Add a filter in the functions.php file which adds a clear attribute to the `<br/>` tag. When the attribute is added, the `<br/>` tag is not removed by WordPress.

```
function clear_br($content){ 
     return str_replace("<br/>","<br clear='none'/>", $content);
} 
add_filter('the_content','clear_br');
```

Then apply this filter on a variable where you need break should come in that text content

```
$specification = apply_filters( 'the_content', $specification );
```

For more info: https://blog.templatetoaster.com/wordpress-line-break-not-working/